# R: how do I subset a dataframe based on two columns in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset the `d` dataframe by the `Profile` column in the `ann` dataframe, whereby I only want to keep rows with `Profile` variable `BP`. The `FID` column in `d` is the same as the `Database_ID` column in `ann`.

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
bdf <- d %>% filter(FID %in% ann$Database_ID && ann$Profile=="BP")
```

Result:

```
[1] FID IID SOL C1  C2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm getting empty rows.

`d` dataframe

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(FID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14", 
"AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22", 
"AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2", "AC30", 
"AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37", "AC38", 
"AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45", "AC46", 
"AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53", "AC54", 
"AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62", 
"AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", 
"AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77", "AC78", 
"AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84", "AC86", 
"AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92", "AC9", 
"AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105", "AC16", 
"AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99", "DE10", 
"DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18", "DE19", 
"DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26", "DE27", 
"DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38", "DE39", 
"DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", 
"DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53", "DE54", 
"DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7", "DE9", 
"DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), IID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), SOL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), C1 = c(-0.00385609, 0.0101138, -0.0146168, -0.0218236, -0.0134745, 
-0.017089, 0.0152448, 0.0134359, 0.00540102, -0.0125389, 0.00463956, 
-0.00416079, -0.000325898, 0.0132781, 0.0130666, 0.00718399, 
-0.0051912, -0.0227934, 0.0364974, -0.0180301, -0.0226556, -0.00585266, 
0.0258924, -0.00994298, -0.00380612, 0.0187883, 0.0103367, 0.00747272, 
0.0191431, -0.00501846, -0.00118336, 0.0361201, 0.00830498, 0.00380194, 
0.00667686, -0.000441697, -0.00170991, -0.0281008, -0.00424591, 
0.0213412, 0.00261405, 0.016154, 0.0098956, 0.0141544, 0.0367203, 
0.0144693, 0.0256731, -0.00218851, 0.0204603, -0.000603019, -0.00504176, 
-0.00917368, 0.00237875, 0.0175946, 0.0188388, 0.0368965, -0.00408476, 
0.00871812, -0.00851917, 0.0252035, -0.00915532, 0.0223745, 0.016866, 
0.026825, 0.0366276, 0.0540474, 0.0386237, 0.0029996, 0.0207176, 
0.0177353, -0.0066377, 0.0343811, 0.0282509, 0.00526683, 0.0459516, 
0.00976286, 0.0259005, -0.00104822, -0.012696, 0.0134071, 0.0231658, 
0.00359455, 0.0194968, -0.000936478, -0.0029218, -0.0058512, 
-0.000837274, -0.0129465, -0.0102079, -0.00559039, 0.0118966, 
0.00147658, 0.0120396, -0.0104779, -0.0315149, -0.0115454, -0.0122457, 
-6.72242e-05, 0.00370599, -0.0164126, -0.0107853, -0.0271741, 
-0.0212005, -0.0445118, -0.0387773, -0.025109, -0.0321735, -0.0398603, 
-0.0266408, -0.0260984, -0.0296337, -0.0185381, -0.0403944, 0.0197937, 
-0.0176322, -0.013238, -0.0071666, -7.27277e-05, 0.00397489, 
0.0335056, -0.00604706, -0.00926438, 0.00706601, -0.0156982, 
-0.0275085, -0.00864179, -0.0247967, -0.030564, -0.00767327, 
-0.0235161, 0.00649758, -0.0329062, -0.0016138, -0.00701695, 
0.00819454, 0.0100377, 0.0250199, -0.0493141, -0.0216641, -0.0244709, 
-0.00466616, 0.016751, -0.0191688, -0.00492488, -0.0162364, -0.0167085, 
-0.0113427, 0.000422333, 0.030274, 0.0317995, 0.00237194, -0.00693838, 
-0.0100835), C2 = c(0.000865365, -0.001752, 0.0189917, -0.023343, 
-0.0340531, -0.0258976, -0.00794043, 0.0173163, 0.00639341, -0.0343077, 
0.01083, -0.0402179, 0.0158751, -0.00262893, -0.0216757, -0.00261259, 
-0.00542089, -0.00515714, 0.0105216, -0.0193606, 0.00692795, 
-0.0117295, -0.0235627, -0.00850041, -0.0156109, -0.00871875, 
-0.0163218, 0.0227143, -0.0161961, -0.0176719, -0.0070994, 0.0262932, 
0.00164033, -0.00969917, -0.0197631, -0.0154387, -0.0194608, 
0.00442207, -0.0234804, 0.00822342, -0.00657274, -0.0092332, 
0.0130892, -0.0345162, -0.0114187, -0.0129497, -0.00306092, 0.0417858, 
0.0262002, -0.0188849, -0.0184154, -0.0109956, -0.0151195, -0.00414531, 
0.010064, 0.0308816, -0.0153337, 0.0157867, -0.0289866, -0.0106713, 
0.000112714, -0.00152177, 0.0184509, 0.0112357, 0.00097954, 0.032083, 
0.0190258, -0.0371498, -0.0307498, -0.00947645, -0.00198995, 
0.015845, -0.0240248, -0.0122369, -0.00107049, -0.0144661, 0.0207883, 
-0.0418619, -0.0123712, -0.0212721, -0.00667244, -0.028512, -0.00522357, 
-0.018842, -0.0123026, -0.00511655, 0.0188473, 0.00739189, 0.0321578, 
-0.015449, 0.0214631, -0.00995001, -0.00144645, 0.00934907, 0.0344757, 
-0.0220224, 0.0121403, -0.00615057, -0.0208969, 0.0313899, -0.0251011, 
0.011635, 0.00536455, 0.0233033, -0.0019204, 0.0273593, 0.00844028, 
0.00181444, 0.02824, 0.0255231, 0.00266055, -0.00850383, -0.0129938, 
0.0268634, 0.0195986, 0.0320615, -0.0026514, 0.0127147, 0.014279, 
0.0553434, -0.020963, 0.00629119, -0.0244099, -0.0080923, 0.0173508, 
0.0485753, -0.00666049, 0.0501603, 0.0029162, 0.0267363, 0.0066606, 
0.00857736, 0.0172693, -0.00827586, -0.0117478, -0.00336638, 
0.00954265, -0.00889617, 0.00290055, 0.0229832, 0.0504569, 0.025979, 
-0.00795356, -0.0135421, -0.00359528, 0.0150037, -0.0105817, 
0.0167827, 0.0110882, 0.00200862, -0.00597284, -0.0188371, -0.00827599
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -153L))
```

`ann` dataframe

```
> dput(c(ann$Database_ID, ann$Profile))
c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14", "AC15", "AC17", "AC18", 
"AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22", "AC23", "AC24", "AC25", 
"AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2", "AC30", "AC31", "AC32", "AC33", 
"AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37", "AC38", "AC39", "AC3", "AC40", 
"AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45", "AC46", "AC47", "AC48", "AC49", 
"AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53", "AC54", "AC55", "AC56", "AC57", 
"AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62", "AC63", "AC64", "AC65", 
"AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", "AC71", "AC72", "AC73", 
"AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77", "AC78", "AC79", "AC7", "AC80", 
"AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84", "AC86", "AC87", "AC88", "AC89", 
"AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92", "AC9", "AC100", "AC101", "AC102", 
"AC103", "AC104", "AC105", "AC16", "AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", 
"AC96", "AC97", "AC99", "DE10", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", 
"DE16", "DE17", "DE18", "DE19", "DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", 
"DE23", "DE25", "DE26", "DE27", "DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", 
"DE36", "DE37", "DE38", "DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", 
"DE44", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", "DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", 
"DE51", "DE52", "DE53", "DE54", "DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", 
"DE59", "DE60", "DE7", "DE9", "DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", 
"DE5", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", 
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "BP", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Dep.", 
"BP", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.")
```

Comment: You can filter `ann` to keep only the records you want, and then use `semi_join` to only keep the relevant rows in `d`: `d %>% semi_join(ann %>% filter(Profile == "BP"), by = c("FID" = "Database_ID"))`. Here's some information on `semi_join`: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html

Comment: or you can simply lose one of the `&` so it looks like `bdf <- d %>% filter(FID %in% ann$Database_ID & ann$Profile == "BP")`